# protractor FOR loop using expectations

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I made loop and now I want to use protractor expectation for every `i`.
Loop works ok, but expectations doesn't. If count is 4, there should be 4 expectations. If I run a test, I get pass, without any expectations(which should be false).

I found articles about that but I couldn't make it happen. I tried with Push, but there is only empty value.
Thanks for help.

```
myelement.count().then(function(count){
        console.log("whatever", count);
        for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
           var o = location.get(i);
            expect(o.getText()).toEqual("something");


        };


    });
```

Comment: Are you sure about this `i>count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware. Almost all commands are promises. If you don't handle them correct it will never work. You will first need to resolve them before you can go to the next one.

Something like this can do the trick

```js
let promise;
const promises = [];

myelement.count()
  .then(function(count) {
    console.log("whatever", count);

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var o = location.get(i);
      promises.push(expect(o.getText()).toEqual("something"));
    };

    return Promise.all(promises);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Full test-case code would help, but I assume that you've forgot to either return a promise from 'it' or define and call 'done' callback, since what you're doing - is an async operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem descrption is not clear. I'm assuming that location is list of elements. So i'm applying each() on set elements called 'location' . It will work perfectly.

```
//replace location with myelement if it the correct one
location.each(function(ele,index){
        expect(ele.getText()).toEqual("something");
});
```